# extension file "curl" is must be loaded

Tags: curl, xampp

Using XAMPP 1.6.7 I installed the community version of Magento. But there seems to be a problem. I am getting the error message 'extension file "curl" is must be loaded'. In another computer, everything seems fine.

(the other computer)
intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual CPU, E2140 @ 1.60Hz,
1.60 GHz. 504 MB of RAM
and XP professional 2002 sp2

My computer is less powerful (Inet Pentium 4 1.6 GHz. with sp2.)

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.menyhart.net/blog/developer-stuff/enabling-curl-on-xampp/

> On “xampp-win32-1.6.2-installer.exe” 
>   you will Have 4 php files to edit:
>
> C:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini
>   C:\xampp\php\php.ini
>   C:\xampp\php\php4\php.ini
>   C:\xampp\php\php4\php4.ini
>
> Open the  files one at a time With
>   “Notepad++”  Press Ctrl F And
>   search\Find “cUrl”,  You will See
>   “;extension=php_curl.dll”  all you
>   have to do is REMOVE THE ” ; ”  from
>   all 4 files Make them:
>   extension=php_curl.dll    And Restart
>   The  Xampp Server. Now Curl Support
>   will be  on.

Comment: Guys don't forget to restart xampp server!

Answer (score 1):

Edit xampp/php/php.ini - change the line:

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

(Just remove the `;` before the line)

Remember to restart the server before trying to install Magento again.

For more info see: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/general/installing_on_windows_with_xampp_and_wamp

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help,

I am using xampp 1.7.3 and just need to edit only C:\xampp\php\php.ini, and it works.

Don't forget to restart the xmapp. :)

Answer (score 1):

For XAMPP 1.7x users, only one file is needed to be edited. Just change the `php.ini` file to uncomment the `;extension=php_curl.dll` to `extension=php_curl.dll` and save it.
You need to restart the Apache server as well from the XAMPP control panel.